# Changing the geometry of the mesh

Tags: three.js

It is necessary to change the geometry of the mesh without changing other components, such as position, rotation, material, etc. How to do it?

Remove the mesh and create a new one with the new geometry is very inconvenient.
I do so:

```
oldGeometry.vertices=newGeometry.vertices;
oldGeometry.faceVertexUvs[0]=newGeometry.faceVertexUvs[0];
oldGeometry.faces=newGeometry.faces;

oldGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
oldGeometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
oldGeometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
oldGeometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
```

but then the number of vertices can not be more than initially. There are empty space, for example, in an attempt to increase `windthSegments` of `BoxGeometry`